# How do I do a complete DHCP Server Configuration

Tags: 13.04, server, configuration, dhcpd

i am new bie to Linux and wants to configure complete DHCP server and how I can assign ips to clients on Ubuntu or windows machine. will it connect clients automatically to my Linux Ubuntu machine or I may give some configuration.

Comment: Not dear it is completely step by step more in detail for beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use command ifconfig  to check whether your machine has DHCP or STATIC IP

```
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

In this type of reply your machine has dhcp IP convert it to static first

First assign static ip to your server

```
 sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

it will open the file and insert ip's of your choice or provided by ISP

```
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameserver 182.176.39.23 182.176.18.13
```

After closing the file Check it via command

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now restart your interface

```
sudo ifdown eth0
sudo ifup eth0
```

Now install the dhcp server

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

now set the interface through which the dhcp server will listen the clients

```
sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

...In INTERFACE “eth0” <--<< type your NIC through which you will assign DHCP IP.
```

Now configure dhcp setting

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Add the following lines

```
# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet. 
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.50 192.168.1.60;
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 182.176.39.23, 182.176.18.13;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
```

***If you are running DNS server on your system then enter the domain name and name server in dhcpd.conf file for example As i explained in [BIND9 DNS CONFIGURATION](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166260&highlight=complete%20bind9) I have DNS server named nefitari.autun.hom and IP address is 192.168.1.5 like as under***

```
 option domain-name “nefitari.autun.hom”;
 option domain-name-server  192.168.1.5;
```

Now start/restart dhcp server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

*If it gives you error like Ignoring unknown interfaces eth0=eth0 just do it again*

```
 Sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

 *reconfiguring network interfaces      [ok]
```

Now lease an ip address from dhcp server

```
 Sudo dhclient
```

*The DHCP server writes all current IP address "leases" to the file /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases so you should also find the lease there:*

```
Sudo nano /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
```

*To releases the current lease* ****once the lease has been released, the client exits.***

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

Now obtain fresh IP:

```
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: amazing you safe my day outstanding with details