# 18.04 Server enable dhclient at start after the network card is initialised

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet

First of all, I may be using an uncommon system: I installed Ubuntu 18.04 Server, and then installed the Mate core desktop to it. The network card RTL8111 was not automatically recognised, so I had to install a driver.

There is a similar question ([How to start dhclient at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301174/how-to-start-dhclient-at-boot)), but frankly I do not get it. There also are many similar questions, but since Linux is so diverse all answers did not seem to work or outdated. For example, I could not find /etc/rc.local and `systemctrl enable --now dhchcd` (from an answer on the Internet) threw an error.

After the boot up, the network card was not automatically listed in the Network as it would in Windows. I have tried to add it manually (I could see 'enp4s0' in the dropdown if I manually added an Ethernet), but even then, the network did not work.

The only way I could find was running `sudo dhclient enp4s0`. Then I can connect to the Internet even though the Network list is still empty and the network icon in the status bar still shows a red X. The problem is, I have to do that again after reboot.

How can I make it connect to the Internet automatically before logging in (because I want it to be a headless server)?

Comment: Generally, in a server, running headless, in versions 17.10 and later (including 18.04) networking is configured in netplan. Please edit your question to add the result of: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` The behavior is likely to be different running with a display and Network Manager versus headless and netplan. Fun!

Comment: Before seeing your comment, I gave up and installed normal Desktop edition of Ubuntu 18.04. And the Internet just worked without installing any additional drivers or changing any settings. I guess one should not try to do something unusual with Linux unless he is an expert.

Comment: Again, if you try to run headless, I suspect that you will *not* connect automagically as Network Manager won't be running. Let us hear from you if you need more help.